# Generate link to PDF asset in MODX with PHP

Tags: php, solr, modx, modx-revolution

My SimpleSearch is configured to return both Resource hits and PDF hits from my assets/pdfs folder (using Solr). The results are more-or-less working properly, but I'm unable to generate links to PDF hits as SimpleSearch uses `makeUrl()` for Resource links, but it only take an integer and doesn't like the file path that is sent for a PDF hit. Here's the section of SimpleSearch snippet I'm working on:

```
if ($extract) {
    $resourceArray['link'] = $modx->makeUrl($resourceArray['id'],'$ctx',$args);

} else {
    $resourceArray['link'] = 'http://google.ca';
}
```

I'm using `if ($extract)` as PDF hits don't have an extract generated... And it's working! When I look at the html of a search result, all the PDF hits get `'http://google.ca'` while Resource hits have their link generated properly by `makeUrl()`.

So how do I generate links to the PDF hits?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($extract) {
        /* KEEP THIS LINE AS IT IS THE ORIGINAL CODE */
        $resourceArray['link'] = $modx->makeUrl($resourceArray['id'],'$ctx',$args);

    } else {
        $resourceArray['link'] = substr($resourceArray['id'], 26);
    }
```

It works! The substr just strips off the "/home/townofco/public_html/modx/" part.